# Which denominations follow prosperity theology?

Tags: denomination-survey, word-of-faith, prosperity-gospel

In the comments of [an answer](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/16839/4188) to another [question](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/16830/4188), the topic of prosperity theology was raised, and someone stated that a large portion of Christianity is in some way supportive of prosperity theology. I am defining prosperity theology as the following:

> Financial blessing is the will of God for Christians, and that earthly prosperity is a reward for those who follow God.

I personally don't know of any mainstream denominations that espouse prosperity theology (most that I've heard of are non-denominational or independent churches - e.g. Joel Osteen's congregation). I'm not asking if prosperity theology is Biblical or not, I'm asking **are there any mainstream denominations that espouse prosperity theology?**

Comment: By and large, this tends to be associated with more Pentecostal and Charismatic denominations, especially in South America, although the term itself is so perjorative as to not be used.

Comment: As it stands this is an interesting question but it is also a list question or even a *yes/no* question. Maybe you want to narrow the scope and make it more about the biblical origins? Otherwise @AffableGeek has already answered with a 'yes'.

Comment: As you noted independent churches are more known for this, but I hear echos of it reaching deep into mainstream Evangelical churches these days. It might not exist in the upper level confessions of these denominations, but it exists in the pulpits and pews. It would be interesting to see an answer to this that really delved into what levels shows up in various denominations.

Comment: @Caleb - I agree, but I'm not sure how to word that question

Comment: What do you mean by the phrase "those who follow God?"

Comment: @Waeshael - Christians (for the purpose of this definition, it would be the same as the site definition I think - any who claim to be Christians)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This a good question but at the same time it is difficult to make a list of all the denominations. Many Christians and Denominations believe in [Prosperity theology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prosperity_theology) but not necessarily included in their core doctrines.
Some notable ones being [Word of Faith](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_of_Faith) and other Pentecostal Denominations.

Let's give one example.

[David Yonggi Cho](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_Yonggi_Cho), a Korean pastor of the world's largest congregation church, [Yoido Full Gospel Church](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoido_Full_Gospel_Church) affiliated with the [Assemblies of God](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assemblies_of_God) , is known for his teachings about prosperity.  He emphasizes giving Tithe, Offerings and Seed Faith. "*The more you give to God, the more you get*" is one of his teachings. His words as mentioned in Wikipedia:

> "We must rethink our misguided thoughts considering material wealth as
>   being equated with sin. We must drive out our subconsciously rooted
>   thoughts of poverty, condemnation and despair. God acts in concordance
>   with our conscience; If our thoughts are filled with poverty and
>   despair, God bless us with material blessing."

He is famous for his strange teaching about the "Fourth Dimension". He teaches that we need to learn how turn On our spiritual tap of blessings which is from the fourth dimension and that we need to practice how to exercise our faith in this matter in order to get spiritual and material blessings.

Comment: Not all the Assembly embrace the prosperity theology it depends on which leader your region is under if a pastor is allowed to teach it. In general the full gospel and pentecostals denominations have a high tolerance and do accept prosperity.

Comment: Prosperity theology is not always a part of core doctrines of any denomination. It's about what the majority of the denomination believe. Even Assemblies of God does not include this in their core doctrine but the majority believe in this.